# R Shiny colResize restore column widths

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shiny, dt

Following up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72256689/r-shiny-communicate-column-sizes-between-r-and-javascript-with-colresize) post, I seem to have forgotten to include an important thing in my question. I would also like to restore the column width that was communicated to R.
How can I expand the code from the answer to my previous question in an idiomatic way to include such a functionality?

Comment: The column order? I don't understand the question.

Comment: I have written the wrong word. I meant column width.

Answer (score 0):

There's a 'reset' method in this plugin. In order to use it, you have to define initial column widths with the `sWidth` option.

The behavior is a bit strange. I found that it is better by initially applying the 'reset' method, and then applying it by clicking a button:

```
  "table.colResize.reset();", # initial reset
  "$('#reset').on('click', function(){",
  "  table.colResize.reset();",
  "});"
```

You can try to remove the initial reset to see what I mean.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(htmltools)

dep <- htmlDependency(
  name = "colResize", 
  version = "1.6.1", 
  src = normalizePath("colResize"),
  script = "jquery.dataTables.colResize.js",
  stylesheet = "jquery.dataTables.colResize.css",
  all_files = FALSE
)

js <- c(
  "function(column, columns){",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('colwidth', column);",
  "}"
)

callback <- c(
  "table.colResize.reset();",
  "$('#reset').on('click', function(){",
  "  table.colResize.reset();",
  "});"
)

dat <- head(iris, 6)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  actionButton("reset", "Reset widths", class = "btn-primary"),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 8,
      DTOutput("dtable")
    ),
    column(
      width = 4,
      verbatimTextOutput("columnWidth")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    dtable <- datatable(
      dat,
      callback = JS(callback),
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(
          list(targets = "_all", sWidth = "17%")
        ),
        colResize = list(
          onResizeEnd = JS(js)
        )
      )
    ) 
    deps <- dtable[["dependencies"]]
    deps <- c(deps, list(dep))
    dtable[["dependencies"]] <- deps
    dtable
  })
  
  output[["columnWidth"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["colwidth"]]
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

## EDIT: save/restore column widths

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(htmltools)

dep <- htmlDependency(
  name = "colResize", 
  version = "1.6.1", 
  src = normalizePath("colResize"),
  script = "jquery.dataTables.colResize.js",
  stylesheet = "jquery.dataTables.colResize.css",
  all_files = FALSE
)

js <- c(
  "function(column, columns){",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('colwidth', column);",
  "}"
)

callback <- c(
  "table.colResize.reset();",
  "$('#saveWidths').on('click', function(){",
  "  table.colResize.save();",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('savedWidths', true, {priority: 'event'});",
  "});",
  "$('#restoreWidths').on('click', function(){",
  "  table.colResize.restore();",
  "});"
)

dat <- head(iris, 6)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  actionButton("saveWidths", "Save widths", class = "btn-primary"),
  actionButton("restoreWidths", "Restore widths", class = "btn-primary"),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 8,
      DTOutput("dtable")
    ),
    column(
      width = 4,
      verbatimTextOutput("columnWidth")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    dtable <- datatable(
      dat,
      callback = JS(callback),
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(
          list(targets = "_all", className = "dt-center", sWidth = "17%")
        ),
        colResize = list(
          onResizeEnd = JS(js)
        )
      )
    ) 
    deps <- dtable[["dependencies"]]
    deps <- c(deps, list(dep))
    dtable[["dependencies"]] <- deps
    dtable
  })
  
  output[["columnWidth"]] <- renderPrint({
    input[["colwidth"]]
  })
  
  observeEvent(input[["savedWidths"]], {
    showNotification("Column widths have been saved", type = "message")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you, though I think this isn't quite what I was looking for. I am looking for saving and then restoring column widths. E.g. have a button that saves the column width in R, then if I change the widths I would like to click another button that restores the saved widths.

Comment: @L.t. This is possible too. See the doc on Github. If you don't manage I will help you, but perhaps not today.

Comment: I have found some time to look into it again and I tried doing it with the techniques you showed me in your code snippets. For some reason I still couldn't manage to program it correctly (or at least not in any stable way). Would you be so kind as to share with me how to do it?

Comment: @L.t. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks but this still doesn't quite answer my question because what I want is to use the value that was communicated to R. With this solution the widths don't really "leave" the Javascript. My final goal was to save the widths to a file and then be able to restore them when the Shiny app restarts. But when it is only stored in the Javascript, this is not possible.

Comment: I meant "when it is only restored from the javascript storage this is not possible". This is exactly point where I am stuck, because the communication between the two languages becomes complicated.